# Convert number to text and keep leading/trailing zeros

Tags: microsoft-excel

I received an Excel file (.xlsx) that has a column like this:

```
1.6000
1.6050
1.7000
5.0
```

And so on. The column appears to be a number type. I need to convert this column to text. When I try to Format Cell and change to Text, it changes the data like so:

```
1.6
1.605
1.7
5
```

This is incorrect and does not match the actual data. How can I change this column to text without losing data?

Comment: Is there a fixed number of leading/trailing zeros you'd like to keep?

Comment: @amiregelz All of them that appear in the file. These represent job codes and not mathematical numbers.

Comment: Is there a standard number of digits after the decimal, or does it vary?

Comment: @Excellll It's typically 4 digits, but I doubt it confines to that standard 100%.

Comment: 50 in your example is supposed to be 5.0, right?

Comment: @Excellll Yes, sorry.

Comment: Have you tried putting an ' in front of the number to tell excel the characters in this cell are to be treated as text.

Comment: In addition to good ideas here, the creator of the workbook needs to learn how to preserve data that looks like numbers but isn't truly numeric. Excel will store such data as numeric by default, and if there is a semantic difference between, say, "5.0" and "5.0000" you have no hope of recovering the true data any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at Format Cells, do these cells show up as Numbers with 4 Decimal places?  If so, then, in a scratch column, set the first cell to

```
=IF(CELL("FORMAT",A1)="F4", TEXT(A1,"0.0000"), "THIS ONE IS DIFFERENT")
```

Drag to fill the column.  Find the ones that aren’t four digits and either fix them by hand individually or make the formula smarter.  Then copy and paste values.